# Iphone/Facebook like sidebar scroll reproduce

Tags: jquery, layout, jquery-plugins, facebook-like, fbjs

[image: screenshot]

It would be great for developers to use these already loaded javascript libraries for this awesome scroll for their iframe apps . Any help will be appriciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use slim scroll. It's very lightweight and works on all browsers. 
http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll

Answer (score 2):

iScroll has built in scroll bars: http://cubiq.org/iscroll